# PuTTY, Cygwin, ssh-pageant: unable to connect to pipe, error: 3

Tags: putty, cygwin, ssh-agent, pageant

On a new Windows 11 system, with Cygwin, using the `ssh-pageant` version 1.4 which comes with Cygwin, I cannot make it work with PuTTY 0.80. The `ssh` client reports "unable to connect to pipe, error: 3".

First, from a Cygwin shell, I can directly login to a remote system using `plink` (the PuTTY ssh command) . This proves two things:

- PuTTY Pageant is running
- The public key from pageant is accepted by the server.

Now, using `ssh-pageant` in the same Cygwin shell:

```
$ eval $(/usr/bin/ssh-pageant -q)
$ env | grep SSH_
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-8x2cLh/agent.127
SSH_PAGEANT_PID=128
$ ls -l $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
srw------- 1 thierry thierry 0 Jan 28 00:49 /tmp/ssh-8x2cLh/agent.127
$ ps
      PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY         UID    STIME COMMAND
      133      28     133       9856  pty0      197609 00:49:50 /usr/bin/ps
       27       1      27      17320  ?         197609 23:54:44 /usr/bin/mintty
      128       1     128       7056  ?         197609 00:49:16 /usr/bin/ssh-pageant
       28      27      28      12312  pty0      197609 23:54:44 /usr/bin/bash
$
```

Trying to login using the `ssh` command from Cygwin:

```
$ ssh -vvv vmiubuntu
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\thierry/.ssh/config
...
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\thierry/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug3: unable to connect to pipe /tmp/ssh-8x2cLh/agent.127, error: 3
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
...
thierry@vmiubuntu's password:
```

The same setup works on an older Window 10 system, with the same up-to-date Cygwin and `ssh-pageant`. PuTTY is 0.79.

Any idea how to troubleshoot this further?

Comment: You're not using "the ssh from cygwin". You're using the Microsoft-supplied \windows\system32\openssh\ssh.exe which knows nothing about cygwin -- and which is also available on Win10 but only if you explicitly enable it, and maybe not the earliest versions. Check your $PATH and if necessary specify the cygwin full path like /usr/bin/ssh .

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you for the precision but it doesn't help much in finding the solution. As mentioned, the same setup (and versions) work on another Windows system. Therefore, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Does another Windows system also have the Microsoft-SSH enabled? Try `ssh -V` (in cygwin) on the working system -- is it `OpenSSH_for_Windows-$version`?